# Show SQL Column Item in VB.NET TextBox

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, winforms

I want a specific value of an SQL Database column to appear in a textbox, but there is an error with my code which appears to be at this line:

Dim lrd As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Public Class Main

```
Dim conn As MySqlConnection

Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    conn = New MySqlConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "server='127.0.0.1';user id='root';Password='test';database='snipper'"
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error Connecting to Database. Please Try again !")
    End Try
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM snippets"
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "snippets")
    With ComboBox1
        .DataSource = ds.Tables("snippets")
        .DisplayMember = "title"
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With
    Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT snippet FROM snippets where title=" & cbSnippets.Text)
    cmd.Connection = conn
    Dim lrd As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While lrd.Read()
        txtCode.Text = lrd("snippet").ToString()
    End While
End Sub
```

What may be wrong?

Comment: what error are you getting, and where does it occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line :

```
Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT snippet FROM snippets where title=" & cbSnippets.Text)
```

to :

```
Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT snippet FROM snippets where title='" & cbSnippets.Text & "'")
```

Note the quotes around the string you'l be searching for. You could aswell use the `like` comparison too :

```
Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT snippet FROM snippets where title like '%" & cbSnippets.Text & "%'")
```

The `%` symbol acts as a wildcard. In this case, that would look for any string containing the searched text instead of string being exactly the same as the searched text.

Comment: Thanks a tone! Worked!

Comment: You're welcome. But indeed although this will be working, the use of parameterised queries as suggested by GarethD is the best practice.

Comment: I will use parameterised queries for sure. Thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

**[PLEASE USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES](http://bobby-tables.com/)**

Your actual problem originates from this line:

```
Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT snippet FROM snippets where title=" & cbSnippets.Text)
```

Supposing I enter `"This is a test"` into the text box, the SQL becomes

```
SELECT snippet 
FROM snippets 
WHERE title=This is a test
```

With no quotes around the text, it should be:

```
SELECT snippet 
FROM snippets 
WHERE title='This is a test'
```

However, if I were to write `"''; DROP TABLE Snippets; -- "` In your text box you may find yourself without a snippets table!.

You should **always** use parameterised queries, this is safer and more efficient (it means query plans can be cached and reused so don't need to be compiled each time);

```
Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT snippet FROM snippets where title = @Title")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", cbSnippets.Text)
Dim lrd As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! Worked!